# mysql cant save my big decimal number

Tags: json, decimal, decode, reduce

I have a number like this
34.59704151614417

and I put datatype on decimal(16,14) but it has saved as 34.59704151614400

it means mysql save just 12 digit decimal
 this is my array

Array
(

```
                [geometry] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => Polygon
                        [coordinates] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 32.34375
                                                [1] => 48.690960390925
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 16.875
                                                [1] => 34.597041516144
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 43.2421875
                                                [1] => 31.653381399664
                                            )

                                        [3] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 64.3359375
                                                [1] => 40.97989806962
                                            )

                                        [4] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 32.34375
                                                [1] => 48.690960390925
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

I understand 
after I do json_decode of my array it reduce it's digit to 12 number

Comment: Please edit the question and show the code used to insert the value.

Comment: I edited it and added my code

Comment: As @Gordon Linoff suggested, show us the code where you insert the values into the DB.

Comment: NO it is not about mySQL and inserting code
I understand after decoding my json data to array  json_decode()
my numbers rounded and reduced

Comment: If it's not related to mysql, you should edit your tags and title to suit the edited question's content.

Answer (score 0):

Set precision directive:

```
ini_set('precision', 16);
```

It is currently 14 and that's why the decimals get reduced. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) link about more information